# How to run Renovate inside a Ubuntu 20.04 Docker container?

Tags: typescript, docker, renovate

I want to run [Renovate](https://github.com/renovatebot/renovate) inside a a Ubuntu 20.04 docker container, but renovate does not seem to work. Here are the step to repdocue my setting:

```
docker run -it ubuntu:20.04 /bin/bash
apt update
apt upgrade
printf 'y\n1\n\1n' | apt install nodejs
apt install -y npm
npm install -g renovate
renovate --version
```

`renovate --version` gives me:

```
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/renovate/dist/logger/index.js:13
let logContext = process.env.LOG_CONTEXT ?? (0, nanoid_1.nanoid)();
                                          ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token ?
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:23)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/renovate/dist/renovate.js:5:18)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
root@3b484953056f:/# renovate --version
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/renovate/dist/logger/index.js:13
let logContext = process.env.LOG_CONTEXT ?? (0, nanoid_1.nanoid)();
                                          ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token ?
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:23)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/renovate/dist/renovate.js:5:18)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong here? Do I need to setup `RENOVATE_LOG_CONTEXT`? If so, how can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the node and git versions. Must be updated or will get that error.

Answer (score 1):

renovate github discussions is more active than this, you should try there next time.

you should look into github repository, check this repository out for ubuntu example:
https://github.com/renovatebot/docker-ubuntu/blob/master/Dockerfile

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32485165)